# Bootstrap carousel item jumping when adding padding to carousel-inner

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-carousel

I have tried to troubleshoot this for so long and no luck. the issue is that the slider is working as it should, except when I add padding to `.carousel-inner` the items is jumping and appearing in the background..

[Codepen can be found here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qVQMzm)

I have tried forcing no padding/margins, etc. but no luck..

**EDIT:** Adding padding to the parent div is not possible(won't fix it) as I'm using `box-shadow` in the items' contents. and it doesn't appear with `overflow:hidden`

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Its because of Bootstrap add `next` and `left` class to `.item` to make it absolute position see this example https://codepen.io/anon/pen/POxyJg

add top:20px; top `.carousel-inner>.next` and `.carousel-inner>.prev`

```
.carousel-inner>.next, .carousel-inner>.prev{
  top: 20px; // top padding
}
```

Comment: I've edited the post, please have a look at it again.

Comment: I am sure it's because of `left : 0;` or `left : 100%;` on .item

Comment: I have tried adding +/- 20px to left and that didn't do it unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm not sure why is it doing that, but you can add `padding` to you carousel ID and achieve the same effect.

`#theCarousel{padding:20px;}`

Now it works well: https://codepen.io/Karadjordje/pen/bYQmBP

Comment: I've edited the post, please have a look at it again.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding to .carousel-inner a wide transparent border instead of padding, worked for me.
In the topic starter's case, the css is going to be like

```
.carousel-inner {border-top:20px solid transparent;}
```

Comment: Please consider editing your answer to make it more helpful. You should add some example code, and explain why this approach works